# three.js material map can't get webglTexture handle

Tags: javascript, three.js

**Create material**

```
 var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
          material.map = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
          material.transparent = true;
          material.side = THREE.DoubleSide,
          material.opacity = 1;
          material.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
          material.map.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
          material.map.generateMipmaps = true;
          material.map.needsUpdate = true;
```

**Get material target**

```
var handle = material.map.__webglTexture;
```

**Description of the problem**

but why handle is always return undefined, Before r69 version can get handle return WebGLTexture but r85 version can't i don't understand Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Internally, the WebGL properties are now decoupled from the public objects, so a THREE texture does not know about its __webglTexture counterpart. The WebGL renderer stores this information internally, in a properties object (property bag).

This makes for a much nicer engine design, but as it made custom extensions to the THREE functionality a bit harder to implement (as you found out), the library authors have since exposed these internal properties.

Here is how to access the __webglTexture of a given THREE texture:

```
var props = renderer.properties.get(material.map);
var handle = props.__webglTexture;
```

Answer (score 0):

Three.js creates WebGL objects for its entities [lazily](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/a4922d637762f2abf0ac7282b2bea8538bf1ee3e/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLTextures.js#L399) so you probably need to use the material at least once for rendering before querying `__webglTexture`. Also it may still be not a very good idea since it isn't a documented property (`__` is its name hints that:)) and may be subjected to change in future releases.